# Google TreeMap withn Sencha Layout

Tags: google-maps, layout, extjs, treemap, tabpanel

I am facing issues while implementing Google [TreeMap](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap) within my [ExtJS layout browser](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html).

I copied the same google treemap example as html file. And gave the reference of the html within `Geographic Spread` tab as I did for other tabs. Other tabs are working fine(so there is no error in how I am pointing to that html).

[image]
But I believe there is some library missing or some additional plugin is required while working with ExtJS Layout Manager.

Any clues are deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to get a google treemap in a panel?

Comment: @A1rPun Yes, within a tab panel. I got a way around using iframe. But it has some issues too. If there is any solution without iframe is appreciated

Comment: The treemap is rendered in a div called `<div id="visualization" ...></div>`. Try to render the div inside your tabpanel using `contentEl: 'visualization'`.

Comment: @A1rPun I have seen your profile, you mainly work with Sencha products. And we do too. Why don't we work together. Our skype id is `stratageeks`, please reach us there to discuss further.

Comment: Thank you, I've checked your application ;) I'm currently employed but I'll work 24/7 if I have to.

Comment: @A1rPun Can you reach us at `skype:stratageeks`

Comment: alright ;) I'll add you.